# "undefined method `logs' for <Selenium::WebDriver::Options."

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver

As a part of my Ruby-watir-selenium-Firefox automation, I am trying to capture Javascript errors generated by a page, and using the code below, a popular code that seems to work for many. When I run the test, it fails with an error "undefined method `logs' for Selenium::WebDriver::Options."
Is 'logs' method not supported by selenium driver anymore ? Any info will be appreciated. My first post so please pardon any mistakes. 
[Code Snippet and Debug message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd4NG.png)

```js
def print_js_errors_on_current_page
  @ browser = driver
  log = @browser.driver.manage.logs.get(: browser)
  errors = log.select { | entry | entry.level.eql ? 'SEVERE'}
if errors.count > 0
  javascript_errors = errors.map( & : message).join("\n")   raise javascript_errors
  end 
 end
```

[image: code and error log]

Comment: you should post your code in the question so we can see what the issue is AND be able to copy and edit said code.

Comment: Hello Alex, If you click on the Code snippet and Debug message Link above You can see the code and the debug point where it fails. copy pasting the code below. def print_js_errors_on_current_page
    @browser = driver
    log = @browser.driver.manage.logs.get(:browser)
    errors = log.select{ |entry| entry.level.eql? 'SEVERE' }
    if errors.count > 0
      javascript_errors = errors.map(&:message).join("\n")
      raise javascript_errors
    end
  end

Comment: It's not for my convenience, it's part of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: code goes in the question. I'll edit if for you...

Comment: Thanks a bunch @alex. very very kind of you. I apologize for making you do my cleanup. my next posts will be more meaningful. I promise. Now I understand how this should be done. thanks again.